# Invalid CSS after "...ules: $modules ": expected "}", was "!global;")

Tags: zurb-foundation, compass-sass

I'm trying to upgrade all the Javascript libraries of a project I got from a provider years ago.
I've been able to successfully upgrade almost all of them but foundation.

The working version has foundation 5.4.7 installed.

So I upgradet it with

```
 bower install foundation
```

As I installed all my other libraries

when I then try to compile it with

```
bundle exec compass compile
```

i get the error

```
error webapp/static/webapp/sass/app.scss 
(Line 14 of webapp/static/libs/foundation/scss/foundation/_functions.scss: 
Invalid CSS after "...ules: $modules ": expected "}", was "!global;")
overwrite webapp/static/webapp/css/app.css

error webapp/static/webapp/sass/stundenplan.scss 
(Line 14 of webapp/static/libs/foundation/scss/foundation/_functions.scss:    
Invalid CSS after "...ules: $modules ": expected "}", was "!global;")
overwrite webapp/static/webapp/css/stundenplan.css
```

Im running a Windwos machine with

- ruby 2.3.3p222
- node 6.7.0
- Compass 1.0.3 (Polaris)
- Rails 5.0.1
- foundation (1.0.4)
- foundation-rails (6.3.0.0)
- sass (3.4.23, 3.2.19)
- sass-rails (5.0.6)
- bundler (1.14.2, 1.13.7)

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll post my solution here.
First I removed my old versions of the gems

```
gem uninstall sass --version 3.2.19
gem uninstall bundler --version 1.13.7
gem uninstall compass --version 0.12.6
```

And then the crucial part:
Move to the applications path  and delete the Gemfile.lock file
then executed a

```
bundler update
```

and now my

```
 bundle exec compass compile
```

works... it throws a few warnings that I'll lok at... but it generally is working